# Save a " with variable in a text file php

Tags: php

I save a variable in a text file but not save " in my text file just saved variable I want to save "$my variable" in the file and then use for json_decode.

I try this:

```
file_put_contents("mytext.txt","$variable");
file_put_contents("mytext.txt",".$variable.");
```

but not work

Comment: Remove  double qoutes from the variable

Comment: [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) would be the counterpart to make the saved data readable by [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode). The vague description of `save "$my variable"` doesn't explain if a syntax literal or variable contents should be stored there, so: unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to save "$my variable" in the file

If I understand you correctly, you want the resulting *output* to include quotes?  You'd need to include the quotes in the value being saved.  Perhaps something like this:

```
file_put_contents("mytext.txt","\"$variable\"");
```

or:

```
file_put_contents("mytext.txt",'"' . $variable . '"');
```

The difference is mostly a matter of personal coding style preference.  Qouble-quoted strings expand variables, but your double-quotes would need to be escaped.  Single-quoted strings wouldn't need to escape the double-quotes, but don't expand variables.

A string value doesn't include quotes, it's denoted to the compiler/interpreter/etc. by quotes.  For the value itself to output quotes they need to be added to the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove double quotes from your variable your code looks like:

```
$variable = "Some text";
file_put_contents("mytext.txt", $variable);
```

This will work for you

Answer (score 0):

if use double quotes in string PHP render with variable

```
$var=63;

echo " variables is $var"; //output variables is 63

echo 'variables is $var'; //output variables is $var


file_put_contents("mytext.txt", "save to file $var");
```

mytext.txt content

```
save to file 63
```